# AS3 instance name strange behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, object, instance

I have number of movieclips which I load on start, they all are instance of their respective class definations, adding MOUSE_UP listener to trace their name is behaving differently for different class objects. What possible issues can be?

```
var ClassDefinition:Class = purchasedItems.item as Class;
var item:MovieClip = new ClassDefinition();

item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(e:MouseEvent){trace(e.target.toString());});
```

It output the name of MovieClip like this "[object bluelamp]"(required) but some other as "[object MovieClip]"(not required), while every object I create is using class defination and they load successfully.

They all suppose to output their name in a similar way

Comment: Is that "(required)" part is your addition or flash outputs like that? Another thing e.target will point to the item that is clicked event f it is the item (child) in your class. So if your bluelamp object contains other mouse enalbed items like MovieClips, Sprites etc those can "hijack" the mouse event. you can try with e.currentTarget or make content of item not clickable by item.mouseChildren = false;

Comment: Yes setting mouseChildren to false worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.target will point to the item that is clicked even if it is the item in your class (child of). So if your bluelamp object contains other mouse enabled items like MovieClips, Sprites etc those can "hijack" the mouse event.

you can try with:

```
item.mouseChildren = false;
```

or use `e.currentTarget` in your trace statement

best regards